# React Calendar gives Error on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

I am new to SP dev fx components and have used react-calendar linked [react-calendar](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-calendar). I works fine on Chrome, Firefox but gives error

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'from'
```

on Internet Explorer. I have seen that it is because of Polyfill not supported with IE11. I tried to add

```
import 'core-js/modules/es6.promise'
import 'whatwg-fetch'

import 'core-js/modules/es6.array.iterator.js'
import 'core-js/modules/es6.array.from.js'

import 'es6-map/implement'
```

but got this error now

```
in Uncontrolled(Component)in ForwardRefin divin divin divin Unknownin Unknown
```

I am very new to this and not sure where else to look. Can anyone suggest me what wrong has happened.

Regards,

Saghir